# Android add Markers on map only for screen

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

on my app i will add more marker on google map by more different json response.
Now i use Retrofit to call end point, retrive json response and add marker on google map, and this is my code:

```
private void getPlacemark(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/v2.1")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit1 = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<ResponsePlacemarks> call = service.getPlacemark();

    APIService service1 = retrofit1.create(APIService.class);
    Call<NetworkResponse> call1 = service.getNetwork();



    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePlacemarks>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponsePlacemarks> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.d("risposta: ",new Gson().toJson(response));
            try {
                //mMap.clear();
                // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPlacemarks().size(); i++) {
                    Double lat = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getCoordinates().get(1);
                    Double lng = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getCoordinates().get(0);
                    String placeName = response.body().getPlacemarks().get(i).getAddress();

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    // Position of Marker on Map
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    // Adding Title to the Marker
                    markerOptions.title(placeName);

                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pin_green));
                    // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    call1.enqueue(new Callback<NetworkResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<NetworkResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            //Log.d("risposta_bike: ",new Gson().toJson(response));
            try {
                //mMap.clear();
                // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getNetwork().getStations().size(); i++) {
                    Double lat = response.body().getNetwork().getStations().get(i).getLatitude();
                    Double lng = response.body().getNetwork().getStations().get(i).getLongitude();
                    int placeName = response.body().getNetwork().getStations().get(i).getFreeBikes();
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions1 = new MarkerOptions();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    // Position of Marker on Map
                    markerOptions1.position(latLng);
                    // Adding Title to the Marker
                    markerOptions1.title("Bici disponibili: " + placeName);

                    markerOptions1.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.gray_pin));
                    // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                    Marker mm = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });



}
```

now i call only this 2 end point and i have much more marker on map and in the feture i will add more marker.
So i would like how i can change my code and add all marker by json resposnse  as they move on screen and remove Markers as they move off screen, showing markers that are currently within the viewable bounds of the GoogleMap as perceived by the user as in this app:

[Ally App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allryder.android&hl=it)

and how can show the marker only in a range zoom, example( zoom > 10)

this is my code for add google map:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1, container, false);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setToolbarTitle("Mobility");





    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




    return v;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources()
            .getString(R.string.style_json)));
    getPlacemark();

    if (!success) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
    }



    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Any help and idea?
Thanks

Comment: check this might be help you https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java

Comment: I know cluster but the solution that i have post on my question is differnt to cluster. I woul show on map only marker  that are currently within the viewable bounds of the GoogleMap as perceived by the user